# Find and remove the longest words in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Write a function whose input parameter is a string. The function should remove the longest words in the line (words-groups of characters separated by spaces, or by a space and the beginning (end) of the string).

At the moment my code is ready and working, but it needs to manually rewrite the methods. In particular, these are .push() (written in the code, but does not work, cannot read property allWords - length), .filter() and .replace(). You cannot use ready-made functions.

Expected Result: 'word wooord  wooooooord. woooooord woooord'

```
function deleteTheLongestWord(str){

    let arrSent = strSplit(str, ".");
    
    let allWords = [];


    let biggestWord = '';

    for (const elem in arrSent) {
        let words = strSplit(arrSent[elem], ' ');
        for (const word in words) {
            allWords = arrPush(allWords, words[word])
        }
    }

    for (const i in allWords) {
        if(biggestWord.length < allWords[i].length){
            biggestWord = allWords[i];
        }
    }

    allWords = allWords.filter(function(e){
        return e.length === biggestWord.length
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(" " + allWords[i], '');
    }
    console.log(str);
}

function arrPush(allWords, word){
    allWords[allWords.length] = word
}

function strSplit(str, delimiter){
    const arr = [""];
    const len = delimiter.length;
    let idx = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let sample = "";
      for (let x = i; x < i + len; x++) {
        sample += str[x];
      }
      if (sample === delimiter) {
        i += len;      
        idx += 1;      
        arr[idx] = ""; 
      }
      if (str[i]) arr[idx] += str[i];
    }
    return arr
  }

deleteTheLongestWord('word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord');
```

Comment: _"You cannot use ready-made functions"_... what does that even mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because of `allWords = arrPush(allWords, words[word]);` and how `arrPush` is written.

The first time that `arrPush` is called, you're passing an empty array `allWords` and the word to push to that array (second parameter).

But because the function `arrPush` doesn't return, you're basically unsetting `allWords` i.e. `allWords = undefined`. So the code errors as there is no `length` property of `undefined`.

The key to solving this, it simply to `return allWords;` as a result of your `arrPush` function so that `allWords` is continually set to the newest (slightly fuller) version of the array.

```js
function deleteTheLongestWord(str){
  
    let arrSent = strSplit(str, ".");
  
    let allWords = [];

    let biggestWord = '';

    for (const elem in arrSent) {
        let words = strSplit(arrSent[elem], ' ');
        for (const word in words) {
          if (words[word] !== ''){
             allWords = arrPush(allWords, words[word]);
          }
        }
    }
  
    for (const i in allWords) {
        if(biggestWord.length < allWords[i].length){
            biggestWord = allWords[i];
        }
    }

    allWords = allWords.filter(function(e){
        return e.length === biggestWord.length
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(" " + allWords[i], '');
    }
    console.log(str);
}

function arrPush(allWords, word){
  allWords[allWords.length] = word;
  return allWords;
}

function strSplit(str, delimiter){
    const arr = [""];
    const len = delimiter.length;
    let idx = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let sample = "";
      for (let x = i; x < i + len; x++) {
        sample += str[x];
      }
      if (sample === delimiter) {
        i += len;      
        idx += 1;      
        arr[idx] = ""; 
      }
      if (str[i]) arr[idx] += str[i];
    }
    return arr
}

deleteTheLongestWord('word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord');
```

Comment: A good answer explains what the issue is and what was done to resolve it. Otherwise the actual issue/solution can get lost in code only answers. At the very least comment what you have changed.

Comment: @JonP I think I overwrote the explanation when I fiddled with the snippet! Thanks for picking it up! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short function that does what seems to be expected: removing all the longest words of a string.

```js
const testString =
  "word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord";
const expectedResult = "word wooord wooooooord. woooooord woooord";

function deleteTheLongestWord(string) {
  const words = string.split(" ");
  const max = Math.max(...words.map((word) => word.length));
  return words.filter((word) => word.length < max).join(" ");
}

const result = deleteTheLongestWord(testString);
console.log(result);
console.log(result === expectedResult);
```

And here is the same function in more lines with comments and console logs, so the process can be understood.

```js
const testString =
  "word wooord wooooooooord wooooooord. wooooooooord woooooord woooord wooooooooord";
const expectedResult = "word wooord wooooooord. woooooord woooord";

function deleteTheLongestWord(string) {
  // Get all words in an array
  const words = string.split(" ");
  console.log(words);

  // Create an array containing the length of each words
  const wordsLength = words.map((word) => word.length);
  console.log(wordsLength);

  // Find what the maximum length is
  const max = Math.max(...wordsLength);
  console.log(max);

  // filter the words array keeping only words that are less than the max length
  const result = words.filter((word) => word.length < max);
  console.log(result);

  return result.join(" ");
}

const result = deleteTheLongestWord(testString);
console.log(result);
console.log(result === expectedResult);
```

Comment: Although maybe not the clearest way to request it, the OP stated "You cannot use ready-made functions" which I presume means no built-in functions like `map` or `filter`. Otherwise, your answer is FAR more efficient! :)

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I think it will be instructive for future readers to see what *"ready-made"* functions can do. ;)

Answer (score -2):

For the loop method, you can use split() or otherwise you can use filter().